# How to make this Javascript function work without Enumerators?

Tags: javascript

**MY PROBLEM**

I have a Javascript function below where I am trying to modify the code so that the functionality works with Chome and other browsers. (PS: I found that Enumerator constructor is not a part of the ECMA standards, it's a Microsoft's JScript addition to the language. And to make my code work for latest browsers I need to use `for..in` loops to iterate objects )

**MY CONDITION**

I am a beginner to Javascript and I am finding a hard time figuring out how to make it work using `for..in` loops to iterate objects. I have 7 other functions like these but I'm sure if someone can help me with this one I will figure out the rest others on my own. Also, `for..in` is just 1 thing that has been advised if there are other efficient approaches to solve this case they are also most welcome.

**MY JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION**

Aside the comments that are present in the code I have put extra comments using /* */ so that you can see the points where objEnum has been used and accordingly advise what can be done. There are 3 places where it is in the code below.

```
function validateRequiredFieldsAllFieldsEnabledAndVisible(objFrm) {
    var objElement;
    var objEnum;
    var blnError = false;
    var blnIsChecked;
    var objRadios;


    //Gets Form contents collection
    objEnum = new Enumerator(objFrm); /* 1st Occurence */

    for(;!objEnum.atEnd();objEnum.moveNext()) /* 2nd Occurence */{
        //Gets Next Element in collections
        objElement = objEnum.item(); /* 3rd Occurence */

        //Evaluates if the element is required
        if(objElement.className == "Required") {
            //Evaluates the Element's type
            switch (objElement.tagName) {
                case "SELECT":
                    if(objElement.value == "0" || objElement.value == "") //See if element has not been filled out
                       blnError = true;

                    break;
                case "INPUT":
                    switch(objElement.type) {
                        case "radio":
                            blnIsChecked = false;

                            objRadios = document.getElementsByName(objElement.Name); //Gets the Collection of radio buttons

                            if(objRadios.length > 0)
                            {
                               //traverse the radio collection to see if there is one checked
                                for(var intCount=0;intCount<=objRadios.length - 1;intCount++) {
                                    if(objRadios[intCount].checked) {
                                        blnIsChecked = true;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }

                                if(!blnIsChecked)
                                    blnError = true;
                            }

                            break;
                        default:
                            if(trim(objElement.value) == "") //See if element has not been filled out
                               blnError = true;
                    }

                    break;
            }

            if(blnError) {
                    alert("Please Fill out the required fields.");
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Try to replace the enum instace with `objFrm.children, and use a regular `for` loop to iterate the collection. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children

Comment: I will really appreciate if you can make the changes in the code and post your answer. I have no one to help me on this.

Comment: `for (var n = 0; n < objFrm.children.length; n++) {objElement = objFrm[n]; /* The rest of the code as it is */ }`. Notice also that JS is case-sensitive, should be `document.getElementsByName(objElement.name)`. Have you translated this from VBScript?

Comment: It would be useful to know what structure or type your `objFrm` is - is it a node/HTMLElement? Is it an array? An object?

Comment: @somethinghere I'd assume "_//Gets Form contents collection_" means a form element ..?

Comment: @somethinghere In chrome dev tools it says while debugging that objFrm is - form#frmdata

Comment: And the corresponding line takes me to a <form> tag in HTML in chrome dev tools

Comment: @teemu Indeed, but it does not hurt to check - you never know, and it should be included in the question for safety. In that case, your suggestion should certainly do the trick.

Comment: @somethinghere Its a form object. Sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: @somethinghere Ah, you couldn't know, I had some ["privileged information"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53497043/asp-page-does-not-submit-in-chrome-but-works-fine-in-ie9-and-below) ...

Comment: @Teemu Yes he helped me finding out that Enums are not supported but I felt I had to take down the question after I found that I need a plan to replace enum, hence this question